# Sagemath - comparing expression with constant always true

Tags: sage

Following comparison in SageMath always gives True, meaning, in the first if condition it prints out 'Not zero', and in the second one it prints out 'Zero'.

```
a = sin(1/2*arctan2(0, sqrt(3)-1))

if 0 != a:
    print('Not zero')
else:
    print('Zero')

if 0 == a:
    print('Zero')
else:
    print('Not zero')
```

Is this supposed to be undefined behaviour or am I missing something?
I know that using .n(num_dec) on a will give the correct answer, but I'm interested in why this comparison always returns True.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is just a bug - probably related to the well known challenges in comparing symbolic expression together with the maxima interface. Note that `bool(a == 0)` and `bool(a != 0)` both return `True`. You might ask for further details over on http://ask.sagemath.org/.